# How can I make triangular form holes on a sphere?

Tags: modeling, boolean-modifier

I need to create a particular sphere which has 4 holes with a triangular form on its surface. I know that I can use boolean modifier, but my problem is that I want to maintain a good topology because I will use this model on an engine. So there are other solutions which allows me to have good topology?

This is a reference of model I want to make:

[image: Model reference]

Comment: Hello maybe show a reference image of how your sphere should look like?

Comment: Perhaps a stupid idea : start from an *Ico Sphere* already made of triangles ?

Comment: Hi, Illidonn, welcome to BSE. We need an illustration (even a messy version) of your desired result. Quite a few variables, here :)

Comment: @StefLAncien my first thought, too.  or perhaps one of the Geodesic Dome variations.

Comment: I'm going to change my proposition so that it matches your reference image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my way: turn a cube into a sphere with **Cast** modifier; connect equidistant vertices (e.g. those circled) with <kbd>J</kbd> or its counterpart in your version and then repeat the procedure three times to make the remaining three triangles. The image below shows it.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create this mesh, mirror and array it:

[image]

Give it a *Simple Deform* modifier, *Bend* mode, 180° on X:

[image]

Then another *Simple Deform*, *Bend* mode, 360° on Z:

[image]

Former answer:

[image]

Beginning with that knife cut and then join vertices, extrude, bevel, etc:

[image]